# Count all span elements inside aspnet label control

Tags: javascript

The label control would contain all matches wrapped in span element.
I am trying to get count of all spans inside a label.

It doesn't seem to be working. Can someone help find the issue? Appreciate all your help in advance.

Code:

```
function countspans() {
                var main = document.getElementById('<%=Label6.ClientID%>').innerHTML;
                var myList = main.getElementsByTagName('span');
                var count = myList.length;
                document.getElementById('<%=Label8.ClientID%>').innerHTML = count;
            };
```

Comment: In what way is this code not working?

Comment: It probably just doesn't do anything...

Comment: I expect to get total count of all spans to display all matches.

Answer (score 0):

`.innerHTML` gets you a string, and strings don’t have a method `getElementsByTagName` … call that method on the element directly instead:

```
var main = document.getElementById('<%=Label6.ClientID%>');
var myList = main.getElementsByTagName('span');
var count = myList.length;
document.getElementById('<%=Label8.ClientID%>').innerHTML = count;
```

Comment: Well then you will have to show us an example that actually makes the problem reproducible … And checking your browser’s error console is a good idea as well.